# save FTP request to string --> Invoke-Expression to DOS

Tags: shell, powershell, ftp, cmd

I want to send a FTP request from PowerShell, through the DOS command line, without pointing it to a saved script.

I have tried doing this by running the following script, but I am getting the following error:

> Invoke-Expression : Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement. At line:18
>   char:18
>   + Invoke-Expression <<<<  "cmd.exe /c $cmd"
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (OpenParenToken:TokenId) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInIfStatement,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

my code is below:

```
$cmd = '@echo off setlocal set uname=user
    set passw=pass
    set hostname=host
    set filespec=spec
echo %uname%>                     test.ftp 
echo %passw%>>                    test.ftp 
echo pwd>>                        test.ftp 
echo cd DIR>>                     test.ftp 
echo binary>>                     test.ftp 
echo get %filespec%>>             test.ftp 
echo bye>>                        test.ftp 
ftp -s:test.ftp %hostname% 
if errorlevel 1 pause 
endlocal 
' 
Invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c $cmd"
```

How can I change this script to make it work? I already tried using `FtpWebRequest` and `WebClient` and was not able to get it to work. Please reply with suggestions about how to implement the `save FTP request to string --> Invoke Expression` approach.

Answer (score 1):

`cmd /c` can't take a multi-line string as an argument. If you want to execute multiple statements, you need to separate them with the command separator character `&`. However, what you're doing here is essentially trying to pass it a batch file in a string argument.

Place the contents of your here-string in a .bat file, then run `cmd /c <path to batch file>`. You don't even need **Invoke-Expression**. You can run cmd directly as a command from a PowerShell prompt.

Comment: thanks for chiming in, but in my first sentence i wrote `I want to send a FTP request ... without pointing it to a saved script.` I ended up doing what you suggested just to have a quick-n-dirty solution, but i am still looking for a way to do it without having to point to a file from within the POSH script.

Comment: Okay, I see that, but what I'm wondering is why do you want to invoke cmd from PowerShell in order to create a text file? Why not just run `"user\`npass\`npwd\`ncd DIR\`nbinary\`nget spec\`nbye" > test.ftp` at the PowerShell prompt? In fact, is there any reason you want to use cmd at all? **ftp** isn't a native cmd command, it's a standalone .exe bundled with Windows (in the system32 directory) and can be invoked directly from PowerShell. Or you might find `(echo user pass pwd 'cd DIR' binary 'get spec' bye) -join "\`n"` more readable.